# sql find new students of school

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

There is a table: `"SelectCourse"` with these columns: `StuNum, Term, ...`
All taken courses from all terms are kept in this table.
now I want to find which `StuNum` is new at this term, for example we have:

```
StuNum     Term
101        201
101        202
102        202
```

so 102 is new student and there is not any courses for him in last terms. I need to to select all students like 102

Comment: how can we identify the last term/current term?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @AbdulRasheed terms are auto number, so last one (or max) is last term

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your post looks like you are trying to find out `StuNum` for which there is only one `Term` present. If that's the case then You can probably use `group by` like

```
select StuNum     
from SelectCourse
group by StuNum
having count(distinct StuNum) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select Terms:

```
select StuNum 
from SelectCourse
where Term = 202
and StuNum not in (
    select StuNum from SelectCourse
    where Term = 201
)
```

Comment: Note that `NOT IN` is a bit dangerous if null's are returned from the sub-query. That's why I always do `NOT EXISTS` instead!

Answer (score 0):

So you want students registered for this term or later?

```
select StuNum
from SelectCourse
where Term >= 202
```

Comment: here term is text :(

Comment: registered for this term and not in older terms